# Quiz to launch pages based on different Endscreens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a quiz that uses dynamic updates on the same page to calculate a score out of 10.

For each score, I want the program to load different webpages, based on what they scored.

**For example, if score is:**

```
1 = Endscreen1.html
2 = Endscreen2.html
3 = Endscreen3.html
4 = Endscreen4.html
5 = Endscreen5.html
6 = Endscreen6.html
```

I have this code below, what do I need to do to launch a different page based on the score of out 10 ?

```
function showScores() {
var gameOverHtml = "<h1>Result</h1>";
gameOverHtml += "<h2 id='score'> Your score, click the score button below to guide patient: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";
var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
element.innerHTML = gameOverHtml;
};
```

Comment: As written the code modifies the existing page with `element.innerHTML = gameOverHtml`, but you are asking for code to launch a different page. It's got to be one or the other. Both would be a nonsense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function needs to be placed inside the header tag.

```
   <html>
   <head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
     function Redirect() {
        //get users score and assign it to score variable
        if( score == 1 )
        {
           window.location="Endscreen1.html";
        }
        else if ( score ==2)
        {
           window.location="Endscreen2.html";
        }
        else
        {
           window.location="Endscreen6.html";
        }
     }
  </script>

   </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can call the function redirect() within showScores() function